# Confused about passing by ref/value in c#

Tags: c#

As in the title something just hasn't clicked for me yet as i'm still learning c#, the following is some really basic code that i'm using just to get the grasp of it.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Pass()
    {
        int x = 4;
        Increment(x);
        Assert.AreEqual(5, x);
    }
    void Increment(int num)
    {
        num++;
    }
```

I know that if i add ref in it will work just fine, however I've seen that using that isn't always the best case.
What could i do instead of using ref and why?

Comment: Return an int and consume the return value in the calling code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Don't mutate state in the caller. Return the new `int` value as the return value. State mutation is to be avoided in general.
2. Continue to use ref if available. Nothing wrong with it except for the state mutation problem.
3. Use an object on the heap, for example `class IntHolder { int MyInt; }` or `StrongBox<int>` which is built-in.

If you tell us more context we can recommend a specific solution.

Comment: how would i avoid state mutation in this case? ( very new to c#)
im using this code just to figure out how this all works, i just want to change x.
I also dont know what the heap is, is there an article i could read on it?

Comment: @Grey By "avoiding state mutation", what is meant is that `Increment` shouldn't be trying to modify the scope of the calling method (`Pass`), as would be possible with `ref`. Instead, it should just return the incremented value, and the caller be responsible for making the appropriate adjustments to its own scope (i.e. assigning the return value of `Increment` back to `x`). Your second line should be `x = Increment(x);`.

Comment: State mutation is often inevitable, by design or could be performance reason. Examples, Dictionary.TryGet(key, out value) or atomic functions, atomic increment, Interlocked.Increment(ref value).  In C++ is state mutation daily business with pointers, C# knows that with ref, out parameters.It is just tool as any other...

Comment: @ipavlu it's just not the first tool to pick. C++ is no different. Passing things by value is encouraged. The language was just upgraded to make that significantly more practical with move semantics. But yes, in principle there is nothing wrong with mutation.

Answer (score 1):

```
[TestMethod] public void Pass() {
    int x = 4;
    x = Increment(x);
   Assert.AreEqual(5, x);
 }

int Increment(int num) {return ++num; }
```

This should work if your set on not using passing by ref.

Essentially when not passing by ref your giving the called method a copy of the original object. So your changes to it in Increment won't be reflected on the original (unless like here you return the new value from the method and use it in an assignment).

When passing by ref your giving the called method a reference to your original object.  In that case any ammendments ARE performed on the original.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You need to change the return type to `int`. secondly, `num++` evaluates to the previous value of `num` so you need `++num` or simply `num+1`.

Comment: You are entirely correct,  this is what I get for typing the code up quickly on my phone. Fixed those issues now thanks :)